# Answer changes slightly when re-run

Tags: functions, evaluation, symbolic, precision-and-accuracy, variable

I am trying to resolve why I get slightly different answers when I re-run my notebook.  Here is my full code:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]
CleanSlate[]
ClearAll[Co, F, A, B, c, Hrr, Qr, G, K, OutHrr, OutQr, OutG, 
OutK, lambda, pr, Zr, Kinv, PhiPlus, Phi0, ninputPhi, inputPhi, 
Subscript[w, k]]

ellValue = 3;
Rbound = 30; 
L = 3;

Co[j_] := ((-2)^(j - ell)*((2*ell - j)!))/((ell - j)!*j!);
F[x_] := Amp Exp[-((x - r0)^2/(\[Sigma])^2)] /. {Amp -> 
10^(-4.5), r0 -> Rbound, \[Sigma] -> 3/2}; 
A[x_] := Sum[(Co[j]*
r^(j - ell - 3))*(-8*(ell - j)*r^2*D[F[x], {x, j + 2}] + 
4*(3*j^2 - j*ell^2 - 7*j*ell + j + ell^3 + 3*ell^2 - 
2*ell)*r*D[F[x], {x, j + 1}] + (2*j^2 - 4*j*ell + ell^2 - ell)* 
(2*j -ell^2 - 3*ell - 2)*D[F[x], {x, j}]), {j, 0, ell}];   
B[x_] := Sum[(Co[j]*r^(j - ell - 3))*(4*(ell - j)*r^2*
D[F[x], {x, j + 2}] - (6*j^2 - 12*j*ell - 2*j + 5*ell^2+ 
ell - 2)*r*D[F[x], {x, j + 1}] - (2*j^2 - 4*j*ell + ell^2 - 
ell)*(j - ell - 2)*D[F[x], {x, j}]), {j, 0, ell}];
c[x_] := Sum[(Co[j]*r^(j - ell - 3))*(-2*r^2*D[F[x], {x, j + 
2}] - 2*(2*j - 2*ell + 1)*r* D[F[x], {x, j + 1}] - (2*j^2 - 
4*j*ell + ell^2 - ell)*D[F[x], {x, j}]), {j, 0, ell}];
Hrr = A[x] /. {ell -> ellValue};
Qr = r*B[x] /. {ell -> ellValue};
G = c[x] /. {ell -> ellValue};
K = -(1/2)*A[x] /. {ell -> ellValue};
OutHrr = Hrr /. {x -> (r - t)};
OutQr = Qr /. {x -> (r - t)};
OutG = G /. {x -> (r - t)};
OutK = K /. {x -> (r - t)};
lambda = (ell - 1)*(ell + 2);
pr = OutQr - (1/2) r^2 D[OutG, {r, 1}];
Zr = OutHrr - r*D[OutK, {r, 1}] - (1/2)*ell*(ell + 1)*r*D[OutG, 
{r, 1}] - (2/r)*pr;
Kinv = OutK + (1/2) (ell)*(ell + 1)*OutG - (2/r)*pr;
PhiPlus = r/(lambda*(ell)*(ell + 1))*(2*Zr + lambda*Kinv);
Phi0 = Simplify[PhiPlus /. {t -> 0, r -> Rbound, ell -> 
ellValue}];
N[0.5*Phi0, {\[Infinity], 20}]
    
inputPhi = Simplify[PhiPlus /. ell -> ellValue];    
For[k = 1, k <= L, k++,
ninputPhi = r^2*D[inputPhi, r] + r^2*D[inputPhi, t];
inputPhi = ninputPhi; Subscript[w, k] = r^-(2 k + 1) inputPhi;]
N[0.5*Subscript[w, 1] /. {r -> 30, t -> 0}, {\[Infinity], 20}]
```

The first run gives:

```
In[36]:= N[0.5*Subscript[w, 1] /. {r -> 30, t -> 0}, {\ 
[Infinity], 20}]
Out[36]= -8.30261*10^-9
```

The second run gives:

```
In[36]:= N[0.5*Subscript[w, 1] /. {r -> 30, t -> 0}, {\ 
[Infinity], 20}]
Out[36]= -8.30188*10^-9
```

My work will not allow these to be different to the accuracy and precision needed.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: I've gotten `-8.30177*10^-9` for every run so far on v13.1 on Arch Linux. If, however, I substitute `-4.5` with `-9/2` and `0.5` with `1/2`, I get `-8.3026055440*10^-9`. Considering this has a fairly short exact form (`(-((1594 Sqrt[2/5])/3375) + 636643/(675000 Sqrt[10]))/54000)`) I expect it to be stable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I will try using the fraction forms and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @eyorble thank you again for solving my problem.  It is a big relief.  :)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.